# Is it possible to use @Valid annotation in console Spring-based application?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` created with `@Configuration` annotated class as a param:

```
@Configuration
class Config {

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public A aBean() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    public B aBean() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Where `A` and `B` are:

```
class A {

    @Min(1)
    public int myInt;
}

class B {

    @Autowire(required = true)
    @Valid
    public A aBean;
}
```

**Q:** Is it possible to make Spring to process `@Valid` annotation in this case?

**PS:** Currently I have following working implementation of `B`:

```
class B {

    public A aBean;

    public void setABean(A aBean, Validator validator) {
        if (validator.validate(aBean).size() > 0) {
            throw new ValidationException();
        }
        this.aBean = aBean;
    }
}
```

This impl seems a bit clumsy to me and I want to replace it. Please help :)

Comment: Class A and B are controller or service or dao layer classes or pojo?

Comment: Both `A` and `B` are simple POJOs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to validate your bean in the process of injection.
You can read 
[here.](http://blog.orange11.nl/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/)

Here is an example:

```
public class BeanValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator, InitializingBean {

private Validator validator;

public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = validatorFactory.usingContext().getValidator();
}

public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return true;
}

public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(target);
    for (ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
        String propertyPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
        String message = constraintViolation.getMessage();
        errors.rejectValue(propertyPath, "", message);
    }
}
```

}

You will need to implement InitializingBean, to be able to validate the bean after it was set.